# Should I enable Intel VT-x/VT-d for virtualized Ubuntu/ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been wandering on the net for some info on this topic without success.

My confiusion comes from the fact that there are some theoretical writings on this topic, explaining the technology briefly and recommending it (again, theoretically), but on the other hand, I've read on forums that there is no performance difference. There are even posts about decreased performance. Some claim increased stability.

My Intel Core i5 2540M - as stated [here](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Intel-Core-i5-2540M-Notebook-Processor.40106.0.html) - supports Intel VT-x and VT-d hardware assisted virtualization. I use the latest VirtualBox and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to run ROS Fuerte.

Should I enable these technologies?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65247/should-i-enable-intel-vt-x/vt-d-for-virtualized-ubuntu/ros?/) by [Peter Roos](https://answers.ros.org/users/2915/peter-roos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 119 on 2013-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Enable it, why not.

For example, I needed to enable VT-d (-x not mentioned in BIOS) to let a VirtualBox use multiple processors.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0